# Is it important to mark a question as answered?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I asked [Can Windows CE 6 auto-run an application on an inserted USB stick?](https://superuser.com/questions/939993/can-windows-ce-6-auto-run-an-application-on-an-inserted-usb-stick) that never got any responses, but while waiting I ran some additional tests that strongly suggest the answer to my question is "No, WinCE does not autorun". However, I do not consider the tests I ran to be complete, and so I still feel like it's possible (though not likely) that the answer I came up with is wrong.

Is the preferred action in this situation for me to

1. Leave the question un-answered until we have some authoritative answer or
2. write up a summary of what I think I've discovered and mark it as the answer?

Comment: It's never a bad thing to share your research, but you shouldn't feel that you *must* mark something as an answer.

Comment: If you are not sure the answer is the solution, wait until you do, to submit the self answer or verify your answer to your liking then accept your answer ( if you submitted it)

Answer (score 11):

Add an edit to your question saying you did some tests which *seem to suggest...* but that you are still not sure if that is the actual answer.

This has the added advantage that your question gets bumped up in the queue(s).

Answer (score 6):

I would add your findings as an answer saying something along the lines of

> Further experiments suggest that the answer is 'No'.

Add as much details as you have that support the statement.

Until another user comes up with a more authoritative answer, that should serve as an answer to future readers of your question.

Comment: For my questions that seem to have an answer of "No", I always express hope in my answer of "No" that I can delete my answer in the future.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, whenever the answer to your question is

```
This can't be done
```

leave the question open. You never know. One day someone might come up with an idea that 10,000 experienced people didn't think of.

Comment: +1 for this, sometime there may be some technique in the future which can solve the old problem

Comment: If it can't be done, then it can't be done. That's the answer. If in the future it becomes possible, you can add a new answer to that effect and accept that instead.